# Nginx container is not getting started

Tags: docker, nginx, entry-point, ansible-container, nginx-status

```
I build the nginx container image successfully. but its not getting started.
```

I went inside the image using sudo docker run -it imageid /bin/sh and tried to up the nginx container.    Find the script used to start the nginx below :

Entrypoint.sh :

```
cd /app/server/sbin/
./nginx -g 'daemon off'
echo "After start"

At the ./nginx command the script is not executing, am also not seeing any error. I cross verified the nginx status.
```

Command  to check nginx status inside my image:nginx -t command.

nginx : the configuration file /opv/nginx-18/nginx/nginx.conf syntax was ok
nginx : the configuration file /opv/nginx-18/nginx/nginx.conf test  is successfull
 Please let me know how to start nginx with that command.

Comment: Run `nginx -t` to verify that your config is ok

Comment: Why not just use the official NGINX image? https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/

Comment: `docker exec` to run commands inside container `docker run` to start container